# $context.domainName Capturing AWS Sever Rather Than Invocation Domain

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Inside of my api gateway I have the following mapping template:

```
{
    "referring_domain" : "$context.domainName",
}
```

And inside of my lambda function I access this information in the following way:

```
const rDom = event.referring_domain;
```

However, when I `log` rDom I see `\"xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\"` rather than the original domain that invoked the api `domain.com`.

Why is this?

Comment: i tested it out, i am setting actual domain name, rather than api gateway execute-api url. can you add more details on actual api definition and how you have setup custom domain name for the api?